# HTML Table Row gets too wide after refresh with JQuery load

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-3, html-table, partial-page-refresh

I have got a problem with a customer website (within Internet Explorer only, tested with Internet Explorer 9). Everytime a table inside a div gets refreshed using JQuery's load-Function a single table row get's too wide as seen in the screenshot below. I already checked the generated HTML Code and the JQuery-Function and I cannot find any mistakes.

Has anyone seen something like this or just know how to solve it?

Furthermore the website work just fine in Firefox and Chrome.

I would like the table to be of dynamic width. The current layout of the page consists of a navigation area on the left with fixed width and content area on the right, which should be scaled dynamically.

**Screenshot of the malformatted website**

[image: 3rd last row is getting too wide]

**Html-Code for screenshot**

```
<table class="tableBenutzerverwaltung" cellpadding="5px" rules="rows" >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td align="right" valign="top" colspan="6"><a href='javascript:showNewUserDialog();' class="NewButton"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th align="left" valign="top">Username</th>
            <th align="left" valign="top">Vorname</th>
            <th align="left" valign="top">Nachname</th>
            <th style="width:16px;">&nbsp;</th>
            <th style="width:16px;">&nbsp;</th>
            <th style="width:16px;">&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
   </thead>
    <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td align="left" valign="top"><label for="User">UserDomain\JohnDoe</label></td>
                <td align="left" valign="top">John</td>
                <td align="left" valign="top">Doe</td>

                <td align="right" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                <td align="right" valign="top"><a href='javascript:showEditUserDialog("b97d5f56-1edc-4dba-b170-f75ccb8f37d2");' class="EditButton"/></td>
                <td align="right" valign="top"><a href='javascript:showDeleteUserDialog("b97d5f56-1edc-4dba-b170-f75ccb8f37d2");' class="Delete"/></td>
            </tr>
```

**JQuery-Code for the refresh of the table**

```
$(function()
{
    $("#dlgBenutzer").dialog(
    {
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: true,
        resizable: true,
        width: 375,
        height: 220,
        title: "@ViewBag.Title",
        buttons:
        {            
            Speichern: function()
            {
                $.post("@Url.Action("AddUser", "Administration")",
                {
                    objectOneId: $('#userId').val(),
                    username: $('#username').val(),
                    vorname: $('#vorname').val(),
                    nachname: $('#nachname').val()
                },
                function(data, status, xhr)
                {
                    $(".UserList").load("@Url.Action("UserList", "Administration")/?random=" + unique_requestid());
                    $('#dlgBenutzer').dialog("close");
                    $('#dlgBenutzer').dialog("destroy");
                    $('#dlgBenutzer').remove();
                });
            },
            Abbrechen: function()
            {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                $(this).dialog("destroy");
            }
        },
        close: function()
        {
            $(this).dialog('destroy').remove();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi, could you mention which version(s) of IE this occurs on ?

Comment: Please see edited post (tested with IE 9)

Comment: My guess on the issue is it's got something to do with the markup that's generated. A space or a tab that gets generated might screw up the padding on IE according to my experience. It's weird. Could you please upload a sample project containing the style sheets and icons? would be easier to pinpoint the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution on my own now. It seems to be a problem of MVC3 (.NET) which I am using for generating the table.

If code is written formatted it seems to add some kind of margin to a random row.

```
    <tbody>
        @foreach (LE.Library.User user in Model.UserCol.OrderBy(u => u.Name))
        {
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 30%; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">@Html.Raw(Html.Encode(user.Username))</td>
                <td style="width: 35%; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">@Html.Raw(Html.Encode(user.Vorname))</td>
                <td style="width: 35%; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">@Html.Raw(Html.Encode(user.Name))</td>
                <td style="width: 16px; text-align: right; vertical-align: top;">&nbsp;</td>
                <td style="width: 16px; text-align: right; vertical-align: top;"><a href='javascript:showEditUserDialog("@user.ID");' class="EditButton"/></td>
                <td style="width: 16px; text-align: right; vertical-align: top;"><a href='javascript:showDeleteUserDialog("@user.ID");' class="Delete"/></td>
            </tr>            
        }
    </tbody>
```

If code is written without formatting (all on a single line) output is just fine in every situation.

```
    <tbody>
        @foreach (LE.Library.User user in Model.UserCol.OrderBy(u => u.Name))
        {
            <tr><td style="width: 30%; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">@Html.Raw(Html.Encode(user.Username))</td><td style="width: 35%; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">@Html.Raw(Html.Encode(user.Vorname))</td><td style="width: 35%; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">@Html.Raw(Html.Encode(user.Name))</td><td style="width: 16px; text-align: right; vertical-align: top;">&nbsp;</td><td style="width: 16px; text-align: right; vertical-align: top;"><a href='javascript:showEditUserDialog("@user.ID");' class="EditButton"/></td><td style="width: 16px; text-align: right; vertical-align: top;"><a href='javascript:showDeleteUserDialog("@user.ID");' class="Delete"/></td></tr>            
        }
    </tbody>
```

I don't know where exactly this behaviour comes from. Furthermore I had to add width to every `<TD>` as columns began to increase their width on their own.

Comment: I spent a lot of time with the same problem. The bug appears on Chrome and Opera, but not on other browsers I tried. Good catch!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the easiest way to fix this is to explicitly define the widths you want:

```
<table style="table-layout:fixed;">
    <colgroup>
        <col style="width: 150px;" />
        <col style="width: 130px;" />
        <col style="width: 170px;" />
        <col style="width: 30px;" span="3" />
    </colgroup>
    <!-- Actual table data goes here -->
</table>
```

This will force the clearly-defined dimensions on the table, fixing most bad behaviour.

Comment: I would like the table to be of dynamic width. The current layout of the page consists of a navigation area on the left with fixed width and content area on the right, which should be scaled dynamically.

I have edited the question accordingly

Comment: You can use percentages instead of fixed numbers, they work too. Just as long as they add up to 100%. You can even mix-and-match, if you want the icon-containing columns to be fixed.